# Need a simple explanation of RegEx pattern in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

/^\s*$/.test(string) - Thats the piece of code I'm using.
I know it is looking for whitespaces. ^ - at the beginning, $ - at the end, * - anywhere

It doesn't matter where I put the space in my string, it always returns false and writes my string correctly (without spaces). The question is why? How does this pattern work?

I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere. I would really appreciate any help. I'm new to this kind of stuff. Thanks.

Comment: You should get something like expresso so you can step through the regex. http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Answer (score 3):

This pattern is looking for empty or "white" strings (strings that contains **only** white characters (space, tab, newline)):

```
^        # start of the string
\s       # character class for white characters
*        # repeat zero or more times    
$        # end of the string
```

Now, since your comment, if you are looking for a string that contains white characters but **not only** OR **only** *(in other words, the `test()` method will return `false` for a string that doesn't contain a white space)*, you must remove anchors (`^` and `$`) and change the quantifier * to + (that means *repeat one or more times*):

```
/\s+/.test(str)
```

Comment: I understand that. The question is: why does it always return false even tho I put spaces for example at the beginning of a string?

Comment: The key word here is "only", in case it wasn't clear. If any character of the entire string is not whitespace, the regexpression finds nothing.

Comment: That changes things a bit. Could you please tell me which combination makes it look ONLY for white characters?
When I use /^\s/ and then string "  something", it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking for? It is hard to know what the answer is when you haven't defined the problem.

Your pattern is looking for a line with 0 or more spaces (`\s*`), AND these spaces must be at the beginning (`^`), AND these spaces must be at the end (`$`). So it only matches lines that only have spaces.

Comment: That cleared some things for me. Thank you all guys for the answers. I can't upvote yet sadly :(